# google serp aggregate reviews

Tags: schema.org, structured-data

I have a website that has pages with reviews for beauty centers, but I can't quite understand how aggregate reviews work.

So I first put in:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Review-aggregate"> 
<span itemprop="itemreviewed">Beauty Center Name</span> 
<img itemprop="photo" src="beauty-center.jpg" /> 
<span itemprop="rating" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Rating"> 
<span itemprop="average">4</span> out of <span itemprop="best">5</span> 
<span itemprop="count">3</span> user reviews. 
</div>
```

That worked fine when I tested it in the Structured Data Testing Tool. But I know I have to put mark-up on each review now.. so I start marking them up like so:

```
<div itemprop="reviews" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Review"> 
<b itemprop="author">Juliana</b> 
<span itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2013-01-12">12 January 2013</span> 
<div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
<span itemprop="ratingValue">4</span> / <span itemprop="bestRating">5</span> stars
</div> 
<span itemprop="reviewBody">I loved it!</span> 
</div>
```

Again, no errors on these reviews in the Structured Data Testing Tool. But now, the Tool says that I have to specify a "http://schema.org/product" with contents about the product. There is no product, it's a beauty center.

Can anyone help me understand what I did wrong?